# Gitlab CI - how to build a local maven dependency before the current build?

Tags: java, gitlab, maven-3, gitlab-ci

I have the following setup:

- Java Library 1
- Java Library 2
- Java application

The "Java application" depends on "Java Library 1" and "Java Library 2" and they are both internal.

"Java Library 1" and "Java Library 2" need to be installed on the local maven repository before "Java application" can be successfully compiled and packaged.

"Java Library 1", "Java Library 2" and "Java application" are separate projects on GitLab.

Each project has a .gitlab-ci.yml.

Each "Java Library" would have something like this:

```
build:
    script:
        - mvn clean install
    stage: build
    only:
        - master
    tags:
        - java
```

I want to tell the .gitlab-ci.yml from the "Java application" to first build "Java Library 1" and "Java Library 2".

Is it possible?

Comment: May be you can create a single script which builds all three sequentially and then use this script in the `Java Application` ci file.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#adding-a-new-trigger -> maybe this is what I am looking for. Will do some testing.

Comment: It seems not to be possible to wait a trigger to finish so trigger functionality is useless for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Gitlab Enterprise Edition, I suggest the solution of dbrekelmans.

That said, another possibility is to setup an artifact service such as Artifactory and let maven use the repos of the service.

Use case:

- Develope Libary
- Push code to Gitlab
- CI builds and deploy libary
- Use libary with maven at the workstations and CI servers

A tutorial how this can be achieved, can be found here: 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/articles/artifactory_and_gitlab/

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [Multi Project Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipeline_graphs.html#multi-project-pipeline-graphs).

> Multi-project pipeline graphs are useful for larger projects, especially those adopting a microservices architecture, that often have a set of interdependent components which form the complete product.

[image]

There's also an discussion regarding multi project build on gitlab here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4194

Comment: Only available on GitLab Enterprise Edition Premium.